# HowlerJS in React

Tags: reactjs, howler.js

Does anyone have experience with Howler in Ract? I have a simple function (handleRave), which should turn music on and off via useState. It works, however I can't stop "Rave" after turning it on.

I'm really stuck here.

```
import Rave from "../assets/audio/Rave2.mp3"
import {Howl, Howler} from 'howler';

function Header() {

    const [musicOn, setMusicOn] = useState(false);

    const sound = new Howl({
        src: [Rave]
    });

    const handleRave = () => {
        Howler.volume(0.8);
        if(musicOn === false){
            setMusicOn(true);
            sound.play();
            console.log("start")
        }
        if(musicOn === true) {
            setMusicOn(false);
            sound.stop();
            console.log("stop")
        }
    }

    return (
        <section className="header">
            <nav className="header__nav wrapper">
                {
                 musicOn === false
                ? 
                 <button style={{padding: "10px"}} onClick={() => handleRave()}>Click to begin!</button>
                : 
                 <button style={{padding: "10px"}} onClick={() => handleRave()}>Stop raving</button>    
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `sound` only once, when the component is mounted, not on every render:

```
const sound = useRef(new Howl({
    src: [Rave]
}));
```

then use

```
sound.current.play();
```

and

```
sound.current.stop();
```

Your current implementation is creating and referring to a new `sound` every time, so one which was previously `.play`ed won't be the same one that gets `.stop`ped.

Another implementation that only calls `new Howl` once would be to use state instead:

```
const [sound, setSound] = useState();
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  setSound(new Howl({ src: [Rave] }));
}, []);
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)